# Python 'print' function 'sep' parameter is not working as expected

Tags: python

I am using Python version 3.7.4 on Windows 10 Enterprise.

I am facing a weird issue with Python's `print` function and especially `sep` parameter.

In Python REPL, when I use code `print(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, sep='\t')`, I get proper output as `1    2    3    4    5`

However when code tries to iterate over a collection as shown below, instead of showing number separated by a tab, it always displays individual value on a new line.

```
numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
for n in numbers:
    print(n, sep='\t')
```

Can someone please help me to understand why its displaying number value on a separate line?

I have attached screenshot for the reference.

[image: Python print function sep parameter]

Thanks.

Comment: `sep` separates multiple *values* within one print, not multiple prints.

Comment: You `sep` only separates the arguments you pass to `print`, in your loop, you only ever pass a single argument. You can use the `end` parameter instead, or unpack the collection as multiple arguments up front using the splat operator: `print(*numbers, sep='\t')`

Comment: Thank you everyone for quick response. That clarifies

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are iterating over the set `numbers`. The loop runs and the `print()` function automatically inserts a `\n` at the end of each item it prints out for display. Hence each item is being displayed on its own line.

If you wanted to loop through an iterable like in your example and have it separated by a tab, then you can do the following:

```
for n in numbers:
    print(n, end='\t')
```

By default, the `end` argument is set to `\n`.